# mod_rewrite breaking jquery

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `mod_rewrite` rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /shopping.php?do=display_product&item_number=$1&d=$2&c=$3&t=$4 [L]
```

It is working correctly on the site but I am working on a new mobile version in a subdir under the root and the jquery bootstrap stuff isn't displaying.

It seems to be redirecting the jquery javasript to another javascript file. I
I thought the rewrite rule would only act on `shopping.php?`. The page I'm testing is called `front_page.php`. Does anyone know why this is breaking the jquery stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this will redirect any directory that is four subdirectories deep, or any file in a directory three subdirectories deep. `shopping.php` is in the replacement, not the match.

**Option 1**

To limit it, you could put something more specific to match the first "directory". It says it's an item number in the replacement, so if it's only digits this will work (only matching top level "directories" that are all digits):

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /shopping.php?do=display_product&item_number=$1&d=$2&c=$3&t=$4 [L]
```

If item numbers are not only digits, let me know the format and this approach can be updated.

**Option 2**

Another option is to put an exception on your scripts directory, so the rule ignores anything in it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /shopping.php?do=display_product&item_number=$1&d=$2&c=$3&t=$4 [L]
```

To add more exceptions for top level directories, just add more `RewriteCond` lines with the same format and before the rule.

**Option 3**

A third option would be to test if the top level directory exists and only process the rule when it doesn't, but I don't like that for performance, having to poll the file system every time the rule runs when there are better, faster options using only matching.

Comment: Thanks. The item number is alpha numeric. The shopping.php page is in the root dir. The stuff I'm testing is in root/mobile, so I only want it to apply the changes to /shopping.php?do=display_product&item_number= in the root.

Comment: That is what is being redirect TO you need to affect what it's matching FROM. I will update option 2 to exclude /mobile/ and that will do it. Let me know and please mark the answer accepted when you're happy with it. The rule hasn't changed from your original, you only need add the RewriteCond before it.

Comment: I added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^mobile/ which didn't work but then tried adding a / in front of mobile  !^/mobile/  which does. One last question -  how do I limit it so it only acts on the file shopping.php on the FROM side?

Comment: Yes of course, the forward slash when checking request uri, well spotted. I don't know what you are meaning about shopping.php. It rewrites to shopping.php. It doesn't act on it, it rewrites to it. In that sense it already only acts on shopping.php. It comes FROM the product URLs in the format your site uses. I think you're just misunderstanding something. What is it you're wanting to change, or you're concerned about? Please use the tick at the top left of my answer to mark it accepted now it resolved your jQuery problem,